# Problemas en acentos cuando se desencripta una cadena json

Tags: java, encriptación, codificación

Hola tengo un problema cuando desencripto una cadena json en el cual un campo lleva un acento en una palabra, cuando genero el json no tengo problemas el detalle no se si está en cuando la encripto.

He probado con las siguientes maneras antes de encriptarla pero no he tenido éxito

```
String jsonRequest = util.convertObjectToJson(req);

byte[] b = jsonRequest.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String jsonRequestString = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Al igual con está

```
byte[] b = jsonRequest.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
String respuesta1 = "";
try {
    respuesta1 = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Así es como convierto el jSON al final

```
String jsonRequest = util.convertObjectToJson(req);

byte[] b = jsonRequest.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String jsonRequestString = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Pero al desencriptarla me devuelve la palabra que lleva acento así dentro de mi jSON.

```
            DomÃ­-nguez
```

Utilería conversión a jSON

```
public String convertObjectToJson(Object object) {
     String json = "";
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

     try {
        json = gson.toJson(object);
     } catch (BDMRuntimeException e) {
        logger.info("Error convertObjectToJson", e);
        json = null;
     }
     return json;
}
```

Comment: El intento de cambiar la codificación llega tarde, debe hacerse dentro del método `util.convertObjectToJson`. ¿Puedes añadir el código de ese método?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que me comentas entonces quedaría así?

String jsonRequest = new String(util.convertObjectToJson(req).getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));

Comment: No creo que funcione

Comment: Listo @PabloLozano ya agregué la linea en donde uso el convertObjectToJson

Comment: A lo que me refería es que el problema está **dentro** del método `convertObjectToJson`. ¿A qué clase pertenece la instancia de la variable `util`?

Comment: Del métodoque agregué ya a la publicación

Comment: ¿Y el objeto reg tiene los datos correctos? Tienes que intentar *tirar del hilo* depurando hasta encontrar en qué paso se produce el error.

Comment: Si de echo el json al final de la conversión pinta correctamente el acento con "Domínguez", pero el detalle es que después pasa a una encriptación esa cadena generada, y cuando la desencripto es cuando ya aparece así "DomÃ­-nguez"